# How to use the 'esc' key to end the program at any point/go back to previous menu?

Tags: python, python-3.7, sigint

Currently I have a program that opens with a menu, the user can select an option and go to that function. However if at any point the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed it should go back to the previous menu or exit the program entirely if it as at the top of the hierarchy.

So far I have gotten it working where if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> then hits enter it exits/or goes back to previous menu. But I would like to make it so that the user should not have to press enter just the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. I've tried using the multiprocessing library to create a process for the main code but that stops the `input()` function from working for all the user input my program requires.

```py
def my_code():
    while True:
        print("a. do something\n")
        print("b. do something\n")
        print("c. do something\n")
        print("d. do something\n")
        print("e. do something\n")
        print("f. do something\n")
        print("g. do something\n")
        choice = input("Please pick an option (a-g):")

        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            function_a()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = my_code)
    p.start()

    if getch.getch() == '\x1b':
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

The actual result would be that if at any point <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed if it is at this menu then the program should exit. But when I run this I get an error

```
choice = input("Please pick an option (a-g):")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Is there a better way to implement this instead of creating a `multiprocessing` thread?

Answer (score 2):

Use the keyboard library to wait for keys

```
pip install keyboard
```

You can use a thread in daemon mode to input the values

```
def function_a():
   print("call function_a")

def my_code():
    while True:
        print("a. do something\n")
        print("b. do something\n")
        print("c. do something\n")
        print("d. do something\n")
        print("e. do something\n")
        print("f. do something\n")
        print("g. do something\n")
        choice = input("Please pick an option (a-g):")

        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            function_a()

threading.Thread(target = my_code, daemon=True).start()
```

You main thread will wait until the Esc key is pressed and then exit killing both your main and the daemon thread.

```
keyboard.wait("esc")
sys.exit()
```

Full example:

```
import keyboard
import threading
import sys

def function_a():
   print("call function_a")

def my_code():
    while True:
        print("a. do something\n")
        print("b. do something\n")
        print("c. do something\n")
        print("d. do something\n")
        print("e. do something\n")
        print("f. do something\n")
        print("g. do something\n")
        choice = input("Please pick an option (a-g):")

        if choice == 'a' or choice == 'A':
            function_a()

my_thread = threading.Thread(target = my_code, daemon=True).start()
keyboard.wait("esc")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Would something similar to this also work where if 'esc' is pressed while in function_a go back to my_code?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you are asking. But as long as you do keyboard.wait("esc") the program will wait until 'esc' is pressed.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, so basically is it possible to do it this way. If 'esc' is pressed in any function besides my_code it goes back to my_code and if it is in my_code it exits.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. That's way more complicated as with this solution you are waiting for the 'esc' key pressed globally. Doing what you want may require several threads or an event system or some more clever way to accomplish having several nested sub menus. I'll try to think something and let you know If I'm successful